# Chrome Css bug with Z-index

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

I've come across a strange "bug" on Chrome where the z-index is not showing properly like in every other browser (including IE).

I've read all related questions related to it and almost everyone in their questions were missing position or overflow.

The link for the website is **[THIS](http://slobodenpazar.mk/?s=&post_location=All&category_name=All)** and there is a dropdown ul element in the middle search that when you click it, is behind the pictures. I've tried for hours all possible combinations with child-parent, different z-indexes, positions and nothing seem to get the dropdown in front of the pictures.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or provide a sample to help me out.

Thanks!

**Solution from answers:** The div element which had the problem, has around 10 div elements above it as "parents". His z-index could not get in the front because his highest parent did not have position:relative, only had z-index which caused the problem for all other child divs below it.

Here is an example:

```
<div>      <---- had only z-index, was missing position:relative
  <div>
    <div>
       <div>   <---- this div with z-index could not get in front because of the first one
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You ought to share code, once the linked site is fixed the question has no meaning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add

```
z-index: 1000; /* or whatever value works*/
position: relative;
```

to your `#big-map`. This will fix it. You forgot to add a `position` to that div, which makes that a z-index doesn't get applied.

The CSS of `#big-map` should look like this:

```
#big-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); */
  /* background-color: #E0E0E0; */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}
```

I agree with Toni Leigh though: in the future you need to share code and a working example, so this question is also value in the future. If you can't share code or set up an example with a minimum amount of code, you can always ask it in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign), where we gladly help you with such "bugs".

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason i had that commented plus i didn't checked the highest "parent", only the few 5-10 above the div so I've thought it's a bug since it worked on other browsers. Thank you very much again, It's working now and I'll share the code inside the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. The fact is that z-index must be defined on the parent element as well. Basically, how is an element supposed to act if the child has a higher z-index than the parent?

The problem is on your `#big-map` which is the parent.

It must have a high z-index, and position relative:

```
z-index: 10000;
position: relative;
```

adding that to your `#big-map` will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Only solved when the z-index is added to the tag for position **absolute** and **fixed**.

```
<div style="z-index:110">
```

No matter how high the value is in CSS, chrome bug converts it to a maximum of 17.

```
z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999;// translates into z-index:17
```

Comment: You're a legend!